# As a Canadian Citizen, can I move a 401k into a RRSP in Canada?

Tags: united-states, canada, 401k, rrsp

I am a Canadian Citizen and was a resident of the US for 11 years. I moved back to Canada recently and am working in Canada. I want to move my 401k to RRSP in Canada. Is this possible? What costs or taxes, if any, can I expect?

Comment: I think you will have to pay the taxes in the US to do it.  You may also have to pay a penalty for early withdrawl.  Call up a Canadian Finacial Advisor they can probably tell you.

Comment: Great question!

Comment: Fantastic question.  If you find out the answer, please post.

Answer (score 4):

You can transfer a 401k to an IRA and then to an RRSP under the following conditions:

> 1. You must have been a resident of the U.S. when the contributions
>      to
>      the plan were made
> 2. The withdrawal must be a lump sum payment
> 3. The withdrawal must be taxable in the U.S.
>
> The IRA withdrawal will be viewed as a transfer only from Canada's
>   perspective. The U.S. will still view it as an early withdrawal and
>   impose penalty taxes, but you may be able to recover part of the taxes
>   paid to the U.S. from Canada.
>
> This method works if you wait until entering Canada and becoming a
>   resident before making the IRA to RRSP transfer. You include the
>   withdrawal in income on the Canadian tax return and claim the transfer
>   into your RRSP, resulting in no additional tax liability to Canada.
>   You then claim foreign tax credits on the Canadian return for the
>   taxes paid to the U.S. on that income, thereby recovering some or all
>   of the U.S. tax from Canada (Ref: Section 126 of the Income Tax Act).

[Source](http://www.howlandtax.com/answers/05Sept21.htm)